# Update a contact group by using a People API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-contacts-api, google-people-api

Hello I need to update a created contact and remove from all earlier groups assigned. In this example a contact is created and it is later moved to Carpenter and now the actial question begins

How do I move a created contact to a different group. That is I need the contact to be moved to BLACKSMITHS group if that doesnt exist create BLACKSMITHS and assign BLACKSMITHS and remove from earlier assigned CARPENTERS

```
function doGet(e) {
  // 1. CREATE CONTACT:
  var contactResource = {
    "names": [{
      "displayNameLastFirst": "Smith Jefferson Jones",
      "familyName": "Jones",
    }],
    /* "phoneNumbers": [{
      'value': "+12345679962"
    }],
    "emailAddresses": [{
      'value': ' '
    }]*/
  }
  var contactResourceName = People.People.createContact(contactResource)["resourceName"];
  // 2. CHECK IF GROUP EXISTS:
  var groupName = "CARPENTERS";
  var groups = People.ContactGroups.list()["contactGroups"];
  var group = groups.find(group => group["name"] === groupName);
  // 3. CREATE GROUP IF DOESN'T EXIST:
  if (!group) {
    var groupResource = {
      contactGroup: {
        name: groupName
      }
    }
    group = People.ContactGroups.create(groupResource);
  }
  var groupResourceName = group["resourceName"];
  // 4. ADD CONTACT TO GROUP:
  var membersResource = {
    "resourceNamesToAdd": [
      contactResourceName
    ]
  }

  //HOW DO I MODIFY A CONTACT so that its must be removed from "CARPENTERS" group and ADDED TO "BLACKSMITHS" group
 
  
  //??????????????????


  
  People.ContactGroups.Members.modify(membersResource, groupResourceName);  
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("Success");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to:

1. Add the contact to the new group (`BLACKSMITHS`), the way you did it in the code you shared.
2. Remove the contact from the previous group (`CARPENTERS`), using `resourceNamesToRemove` at [contactGroups.members.modify](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/contactGroups.members/modify).

Check the example below.

#### Code snippet:

```
// 1. Create Blacksmiths group if doesn't exist, add contact to group:
var groupNameToAdd = "BLACKSMITHS";
var groupToAdd = groups.find(group => group["name"] === groupNameToAdd);
if (!groupToAdd) { // Create group if doesn't exist
  var groupToAddResource = {
    contactGroup: {
      name: groupNameToAdd
    }
  }
  groupToAdd = People.ContactGroups.create(groupToAddResource);
}
var groupToAddResourceName = groupToAdd["resourceName"];
var membersToAddResource = {
  "resourceNamesToAdd": [
    contactResourceName
  ]
}
People.ContactGroups.Members.modify(membersToAddResource, groupToAddResourceName);
// 2. Remove contact from Carpenters:
var groupNameToRemove = "CARPENTERS";
var groupToRemove = groups.find(group => group["name"] === groupNameToRemove);
if (groupToRemove) { // Check that group exists
  var groupToRemoveResourceName = groupToRemove["resourceName"];
  var membersToRemoveResource = {
    "resourceNamesToRemove": [
      contactResourceName
    ]
  }
  People.ContactGroups.Members.modify(membersToRemoveResource, groupToRemoveResourceName);
}
```